# Negative margin in Firefox not working

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, plugins, margin

I have been working on a website that has a large slideshow on the top of the page, then has a row of content that needs to set over part of the slideshow. I had this all styled and working fine until I started using this jQuery slideshow plugin: http://responsiveslides.com/

Now in Firefox the 3 columns of data is no longer sitting over the reflection of the slideshow photo, but it is working perfectly fine in Safari and Chrome. It looks like the height is somehow getting expanded or something. I'm not really sure.

I have tried everything I can think of doing, but the fact that it works in other browsers is weird.

The link to my site is: http://marvell.wpengine.com/

Thanks, 
Dylan

Answer (score 0):

It is all because of `position` property. User `position:absolute` instead of `position:relative` in your `.home-features-row` class. Update your CSS like below.

```
.home-features-row {
margin-top: -268px;
/*position: relative;*/ 
position:absolute;
z-index: 100;
background:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use absolute positioning if I don't have to. It works good how it is now in WebKit, so I don't know why Firefox is having a problem with my current code. The negative margin just doesn't seem to be registering or something for some reason. Like I said, it's only after using this plugin that it doesn't work, so there must be something about it that is messing it up.